# Loading c++ source code from .txt file

Tags: c++

```
void checkSettings()
{
    string STRING;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("C:\Users\Jakereid\Desktop\Settings.txt");
    while (!infile.eof) 
    {
        getline(infile, STRING);
        cout << STRING;
    }
    infile.close();

}
```

So I have a function called checkSettings, and it was just a long list of setmenu values:

```
menu.setValue(Tab_Menu, Menu_Custom2, 0);
```

It worked perfectly when it was in the source code under check settings, but what I want to do now is when the application starts is to load what ever is in the current settings.txt fileinto the check settings function. So what I want to do is to be able to have:

```
void checkSettings()
{
  Contents of the .txt file
}
```

I've tried following a few different tutorials but have had no luck. Thank you :)

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstand of what C++ is. What you're trying to do is impossible. C++ is not a scripting language -- the entire program needs to be compiled before running. You cannot feed a program lines of C++ and expect it to run.

Comment: Also, you seem to be expecting `eof` to predict the future and tell you what will happen in a future read attempt. That won't work either.

Comment: You could include some file (either generated, or manually created) using `#include` directive. (re)compillation of the program is still required.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to have a .txt file, which, when your application starts, is compiled from C++ into machine code which will directly be executed when your application calls the `checkSettings()` method just as if it was `#include`d statically? If this is what you want, good luck with that waste of time. Imho, even writing a custom DSL JIT compiler would be easier... @ColinBasnett theoretically you can.

Comment: @jotik In theory anything is possible, but it would be a pointless exercise.

Comment: @ColinBasnett thats what I said.

Comment: `while (!infile.eof)` Where did you learn this? We need to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with C++ directly. C++ is a compiled language. What you can potentially do is call your settings file in a different language. For eg, there is a boost interface to call [python scripts from c++.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html)

You may also be able to use [Lua.](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/minimal-example-lua-function-cpp.html)

Since these are not compiled languages, the code in your settings file can differ, and this will still work.

Comment: Strictly speaking there's no such thing as "a compiled language", only convention, and there do exist C++ _interpreters_.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work directly because `C++` is a compiled language, and the settings file is different in each environment.

Instead, you should parse the settings file in your code and load the settings based on it.

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense actually. So what I would do is i would create say: Load settings.ini, let "custom1 = 1" = "menu.setValue(Tab_Menu, Menu_Custom1, 1)"

Comment: Strictly speaking there's no such thing as "a compiled language", only convention, and there do exist C++ _interpreters_.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, I would agree with that statement, but it may be orthogonal to the OP.